# Flink with Log4j2

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We are running a flink job using v.1.13.2 and setup/configured logging using log4j(classic/pre-log4j2). We want to upgrade to and use Log4j2 instead and could not find any way to do that. Wondering if there are any teams who went down this path to try to upgrade Log4j. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Log4j2 has been the default logger since Flink 1.11. In order to be using log4j v1, there must be some configuration in place that needs to be removed / updated. See the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/advanced/logging/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Although the log configuration file of flink is named log4j.properties, it actually use log4j2,as david said.